# Can I access enemy information during battles in FFXIII?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

In Final Fantasy XIII, most enemy units have protection and/or weakness against certain damage types.

Is there any way for me to view this information **during a battle**? Are there any symbols on the edge of the screen I can learn to decode that show this information?

I know it can be viewed in the Data Log menu outside of battles, but I don't have the energy to try and remember such things.

Comment: I thought L2 or R2 gave you that.  Might be thinking of a different one, though.

Comment: @Frank If that's true, it would be awesome. :) I couldn't find anything searching for it (just kept getting wiki sites listing stats) and just randomly pushing buttons didn't occur. Hopefully I can check tonight if the mini-mes sleep.

Comment: I'll poke around, see if I can figure it out.  Haven't gotten around to platinuming it anyways...

Comment: Are you aware that your title says Final Fantasy ***12***? You can setup a gambit to automatically cast Libra in 12, but I do not think this applies because you tagged this question FF13.

Comment: I tried to suggest an edit to correct the title, but the author rejected it for being "too minor". I clicked on the question (from another location on SE) thinking it was definitely a FF12 question.

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: @Ellesedil I didn't reject anything. Thanks for noticing. :) Thanks for fixing it,Frank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple.  Press R1.  That will give you any information you've gleaned on the current enemies.  You can cycle through your current enemies by pressing R1 or L1.  If you don't have anything on them, cast Libra on them, and then press R1.  That will do the trick.